# Partial sum of polygamma

Tags: sequences-and-series, polygamma

Do you know what kind of process use mathwolfram in determining
\begin{align}
&\sum_{m = 1}^{n}\left[\frac{1}{-s + m} + \frac{1}{s + m}\right]
\\[3mm] = &\ \Psi_{0}\left(-s + n + 1\right) + \Psi_{0}\left(s + n + 1\right)
\\[2mm] - &\
\,\Psi_{0}\left(1 - s\right) - \Psi_{0}\left(s + 1\right)
\end{align}

giving literature reference $?$.

Comment: $\Psi_0$ is just the regular digamma function. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Series_formula for details on how it relates to sum of reciprocals.

Comment: $$\mbox{Use}\quad\sum_{m = 1}^{n}a_{m} =
\sum_{m = 0}^{n - 1}a_{m + 1} =
\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}\left(a_{m + 1} - a_{m + 1 + n}\,\,\,\,\,\right)$$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}\left({1 \over m + a} - {1 \over m + b}\right) = \Psi_{0}\left(b\right) -  \Psi_{0}\left(a\right)$. See [A & S Table](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm).